# Why Can't Computers Off My Network See the Site?

Tags: ip

Have just set up Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc. on my Ubuntu OS, and I was wondering why computers that are not on my network can not see the basic index.html that Apache uses as the default. I set up the static ip address for my computer, and I use `192.168.1.100` for computers to view the simple site.

Is there something I am missing that will allow others to access my site? (It is REALLY simple; no graphics, CSS, etc.)

Comment: What type of network are we talking about?

Comment: What does the network administrator say?

Comment: I am the network administrator. This is just for experience and writing server-side code once I register the domain name and get things running. I know the router is Linksys and that it supports 802.11g. (I'll get one that supports `n` since everything in my house does) What else should I find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly clear, but if your computer is in a network behind a NAT router, you will probably need to forward port 80 from that router to your computer.

Of course, that means you will need to give your router/ISP IP out instead of your computer IP. You could, of course, use a dynamic DNS setup that you have a domain name that gets updated every time your IP change. From there, you can give out that domain name to other people instead. Here is one service that provides that setup and instructions:

http://dyn.com/dns/

That said, this may not be allowed by your ISP. Please consult your TOS or AUP that is provided with your Internet access account.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try to find all of this out and post results and extra info.

Answer (score 3):

`192.168.1.100` is a non-routable, local IP address. Other machines on other networks will not be able to reach your machine with that IP address. In fact, they may have their own local machine with that same IP address. The 192.168 range is specifically reserved for local use.

Answer (score 1):

you need to get a 'real' ip address that is rotatable from outside your network, or like mentioned above you can setup a port forward rule on your gateway device, typically it would look something like this:

from: any
from port: 80
to: 192.168.1.100
to port: 80

that way people from outside can reach your server. you also need to find out what your IP address is (often given to you from your ISP), http://www.whatismyip.com/ will help you with this. if this ip is dynamic (IP changes over time), then you need to get a dynamic DNS service such as dyndns to help you keep track of what your ip is at any given time.